# how to convert static variables in class to json

Tags: java, json, gson

Hi I have a class Constants that contain only static variables.public class Constants

```
public class Constant
{
    public static class A
    {
        public static class B
        {
            public static final int  COLUMN = 0;
            public static final String  TYPE =  ColumnType.INPUT;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to convert this class to JSON ?

I was using gson, but apparently it ignores static variables. So how can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure which field modifiers GSON ignores with [this method](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithModifiers%28int...%29) on the `GsonBuilder` class.

Comment: No i actually i want the contrary, gson always ignores static variables, I want it to take them into account. (or use another library that does)

Comment: And he just explained how you would do that.

Comment: See https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization, if you want to include static, change it to just ignore transient, since you will override the the default of both transient and static to just transient.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm missing smthg, doesn't `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .excludeFieldsWithModifier(Modifier.STATIC)
    .create();` *Exclude* the static variables ? as in the static variables won't be in the JSON string ?

Comment: just put in `Modifier.TRANSIENT`, then it will override the default of `Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.TRANSIENT`

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is correct. For clarity here is a working example. You can use the GsonBuilder class with the method [excludeFieldsWithModifiers.](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithModifiers%28int...%29)

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder  = new GsonBuilder();
    // Allowing the serialization of static fields
    gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT);
    // Creates a Gson instance based on the current configuration
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    String json = gson.toJson(objectToSerialize);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: The 3rd line in the example should start with json, instead of son.