# JSON parse using Gson giving null

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a JSON response documents using Gson but after parse it's giving me a null value

My JSON response is a Array of Documents

Java Code

```
//Code to convert the response into JSON
   String res = gson.toJson(results);
//Parse the JSON
   java.lang.reflect.Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Objects.JsonResponse>>() {}.getType();

   List<Objects.JsonResponse>  resp =  gson.fromJson(res, collectionType);
   System.out.println(resp.get(2).getName());
```

JAVA Object

```
   package Objects;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class JsonResponse {
    @SerializedName("product_id")
    public static String product_id;  //17
    @SerializedName("create_date")
    public static String create_date; //45
    @SerializedName("image_small")
    public static String image_small; //85
    @SerializedName("image_large")
    public static String image_large;  //133
    @SerializedName("name")
    private static String name;  //174
    @SerializedName("description")
    public static String description; //266
    @SerializedName("tagline")
    public static List<String> tagline;
    @SerializedName("category")
    public static List<String> category;
    @SerializedName("catlevel0")
    public static List<String> catlevel0;
    @SerializedName("catlevel1")
    public static List<String> catlevel1;
    @SerializedName("catlevel2")
    public static List<String> catlevel2;
    @SerializedName("color")
    public static List<String> color;
    @SerializedName("size")
    public static List<String> size;
    @SerializedName("_version_")
    public static String _version_;
    @SerializedName("product_id")
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public static void setName(String name) {
        JsonResponse.name = name;
    }
}
```

JSON document to be parsed is:

```
[
  {
    "product_id": "prod3400008",
    "create_date": "2011-02-17T00:00:00Z",
    "image_small": "/hul_images/small/17_Rexona.jpg",
    "image_large": "/hul_images/large/17_Rexona.jpg",
    "name": "Small Shell Cluster Loop Earrings",
    "description": "Small Shell Cluster Loop Earrings",
    "tagline": [
      "B1G1 75% Off Jewelry "
    ],
    "category": [
      "Earrings"
    ],
    "catlevel0": [
      "Accessories"
    ],
    "catlevel1": [
      "Jewelry"
    ],
    "catlevel2": [
      "Earrings"
    ],
    "color": [
      "Clearly Coral",
      "Mocha Brown",
      "Blue Lagoon",
      "Hunter Green",
      "Medium Purple"
    ],
    "_version_": 1527034576315089000
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not a solutions, more like a tip**. I found out the problem in your question. The problem is with the json array.  If you remove all the arrays and just an object, this problem wont come. I dont know if you are aware of that already.

Please try the following json

`{
  "product_id": "prod3400008",
  "create_date": "2011-02-17T00:00:00Z",
  "image_small": "/hul_images/small/17_Rexona.jpg",
  "image_large": "/hul_images/large/17_Rexona.jpg",
  "name": "Small Shell Cluster Loop Earrings",
  "description": "Small Shell Cluster Loop Earrings",
  "_version_": 1527034576315089000
}`

I removed all the arrays.

I have also removed the static declaration of your class `JsonResponse`, and static declaration of all your member variables.

And this is try this code:

`Gson gson = new Gson();
    String res = gson.toJson(results);
    JsonResponse response = gson.fromJson(results, JsonResponse.class);
    System.out.println(response.product_id);
    System.out.println(response.create_date);`

Hope this will help to figure out the problem. If you still cant find out, let me know... I will try harder... :-)

Comment: I am not understanding how to remove the arrays from the response. Could you put some light on this area!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's giving you null because you messed up your annotations...

Also, remove `static` from all the methods and fields, you are trying to make instance variables, not class variables.

```
@SerializedName("product_id") // <---- not right
public String getName() { // <--- removed "static"
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. But i tried after removing it.. But no success

Answer (score 0):

Object attributes are static and you should tell the GsonBuilder to serialize it.

follow this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116537/how-to-convert-static-variables-in-class-to-json) for more information.

Better practice would be not to make pojo class filed as static :)